Select automatic another table entry if selected entry does not exist
I have in my MySQL Table e.g. 4 Entries.



ID
IMAGE_ID
USER_ID
IMAGE




0
0
0
no_image.jpg


1
1000
1
1.jpg


2
1000
2
2.jpg


3
1001
3
3.jpg



From Property i get a Value to select a specific IMAGE_ID and get the Result
db.query(
  "SELECT i.*, u.username, u.user_avatar, u.user_hash, u.user_prefix " +
  "FROM pix_images_chat i " +
  "LEFT JOIN pix_users u ON i.user_id = u.user_hash " +
  "WHERE i.image_id = ? " +
  "ORDER BY chat_date DESC",
[imageID],

The USER part is initially unimportant for the question.
If i enter the IMAGE_ID "1000", i get as result 2 Values from SQL. So far so good.
If i enter the Value 1003 in IMAGE_ID, i get no Results.
Can I change the SELECT statement so that I automatically read IMAGE_ID "0" if reading IMAGE_ID not exist in my Table?
SELECT i.*, IF(i.image_id = '', 0, i.image_id), u.user....
... does not help.
Thanks for any help

Start with a table (or virtual VALUES clause) of IDs that you want, then left join everything else.

Add OR ? NOT IN (SELECT image_id FROM pix_images_chat) and i.image_id = 0 to WHERE. Probably not the most efficient, but simple

It would likely be most efficient, if you implement this logic within your application (you have tagged react), not in SQL itself.
You could try: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
For example, your boolean expression could resolve something like count(*) == 0.
But then you must query the at least database twice; Counting the result. If they are present, a second time. This does not scale well in big databases.
Its wise to design the behaviour on your data, within your application, wile using as little sql statements as needed and as much as required, to design data driven descition making.

My application is a kind of comment function that is supposed to insert an existing user as a commenter in the first post if no comment has been made yet.
I had hoped that this would be possible in SQL alone, since I had already started a query to the SQL database in the application itself and would let SQL decide the choice. This way I would get the data I need in one go.

Shure, but as I already said: You should design your application and database, considering the apps' complexity. How does it behave on size of 100 (speed/memory), 1000, 1 million and so on.

OK, I've come to terms with adjusting the WHERE clause. This means that the alternative commenter is always visible in the comment function, but that's OK. It's the simplest way. WHERE i.image_id = ? OR i.image_id = '0' 
